# How to keep align environment from getting cut by end of page

Tags: align, margins, page-breaking

I have the following equasions:

```
    \begin{align}\label{eq11}
        \begin{split}
        & s_{xy}=(x_p-x_s)L_y\\
        & s_{xz}=(x_p-x_s)L_z\\
        & s_{yx}=(y_p-y_s)L_x\\
        & s_{yz}=(y_p-y_s)L_z\\
        & s_{zx}=(z_p-z_s)L_x\\
        & s_{zy}=(z_p-z_s)L_y\\
        & a_{xyz} = |(x_p-x_s)(y_p-y_s)(z_p-z_s)|\\
        & a_{xy} = |(x_p-x_s)(y_p-y_s)|\\
        & a_{xz} = |(x_p-x_s)(z_p-z_s)|\\
        & a_{yz} = |(y_p-y_s)(z_p-z_s)|\\
        & c_{xy} = x_sy_p-x_py_s\\
        & c_{xz} = x_sz_p-x_pz_s\\
        & c_{yz} = y_sz_p-y_pz_s\\
        \end{split}
    \end{align}
```

The equations are exceeding the lower edge of the page as demonstrated in the image:

[image]

As this is a paper, I wish all the equation to stay on one page (no page breaks in the middle), and I do wish to save as much space as possible.

How can I keep the `\align{}` environment from getting cut?

Comment: Are you ok with a page break occurring in the middle of the group of aligned equations? Please advise.

Comment: I have added an edit.

Comment: I've updated my answer to incorporate the fact that a page break between the equations is not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I edited this answer after the OP clarified that a page break within the group of equations is forbidden.)

Some comments and observations:

- Since you've ruled out allowing a page break within the group of 13 equations, a commonly given piece of advice -- to allow page breaks either globally, by issuing an `\allowdisplaybreaks` directive, or selectively, by issuing a suitably placed `\displaybreak` directive, does not apply.

  Anyway, to enable such page breaks, you'd have to get rid of the `split` wrapper (and issue 12 `\notag` directives to suppress equation numbers for 12 of the 13 individual equations). This is because `\allowdisplaybreaks` has no effect on equations contained in `split`, `aligned`, `gathered`, and `alignedat` environments.
- The obvious alternative is to issue a `\clearpage` directive immediately before `\begin{align}`. The upsides are that all 13 equations will occur on a single page and that the equation won't protrude into the bottom margin. The [serious!] downside is that there may be a considerable amount of wasted whitespace at the bottom of the page that precedes the group of equations.

  In case, say, only the final equations of the 13 equations would protrude into the bottom margin, you might be able to avoid the big blob of wasted whitespace by issuing an `\enlargethispage{1.1\baselineskip}` directive before `\begin{align}`.
- Finally, you could contemplate indulging in a compromise of sorts. Since the group of 13 equations appears to be consist of groups of 6, 4, and 3 subequations, you might employ a `subequations` wrapper and employ two or three separate `align/split` environments inside the `subequations` environment. LaTeX will then automatically insert a page break between the groups as needed.

  After all, if you can tell a story about the group of 13 equations, it shouldn't be too difficult to tell a story about a group of 13 equations that consists of 3 subgroups, right?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % superset of 'amsmath' package
\usepackage[paperheight=6cm,margin=1cm]{geometry} % just for this example
\pagestyle{empty} % just for this example

\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
    % note the use of 'equation' instead of 'align'
    \begin{equation}\label{eq11a}\begin{split}
        s_{xy} &= (x_p-x_s)L_y\\
        s_{xz} &= (x_p-x_s)L_z\\
        s_{yx} &= (y_p-y_s)L_x\\
        s_{yz} &= (y_p-y_s)L_z\\
        s_{zx} &= (z_p-z_s)L_x\\
        s_{zy} &= (z_p-z_s)L_y
    \end{split}\end{equation}
    \begin{equation}\label{eq11b}\begin{split}
        a_{xyz} &=  \mathrlap{|(x_p-x_s)(y_p-y_s)(z_p-z_s)|}\\
        a_{xy}  &=  |(x_p-x_s)(y_p-y_s)|\\
        a_{xz}  &=  |(x_p-x_s)(z_p-z_s)|\\
        a_{yz}  &=  |(y_p-y_s)(z_p-z_s)|
    \end{split}\end{equation}
    \begin{equation}\label{eq11c}\begin{split}    
        c_{xy}  &=  x_sy_p-x_py_s\\
        c_{xz}  &=  x_sz_p-x_pz_s\\
        c_{yz}  &=  y_sz_p-y_pz_s
    \end{split}\end{equation}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have tried using your `subequations ` solution but got a very high spacing at the top and bottom of each subquestion (very space-wasteful). I have Altered your solution using `gather` instead of `equation` to start each new subquestion. This gave me a better result in terms of the vertical spacing. You can update your answer if you wish. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @havakok - Thanks. I'm not sure, though, if I understand your comment correctly. For sure, if I replace the three `equation` environments with `gather` environments, I get *more*, not less, vertical whitespace between the groups of equations. Is there maybe something else about your actual document setup that I'm not aware of?

Comment: I am using `\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}`. Maybe that is the difference?

Comment: @havakok - The `article` document class employs `\raggedbottom`, whereas the `IEEEtran` document class employs `\flushbottom` (as well as a two-column layout). What you've experienced is a side-effect of this difference. The `equation` environments are actually *more parsimonious*, space-wise, than the `gather` environments. However, this parsimony isn't rewarded here, as LaTeX then expands the vertical whitespace between the groups of equations in order to re-establish `\flushbottom`. (To double-check, insert the instruction `\raggedbottom` after `\begin{document}` and recompile.)